# Read all values from dynamically added text boxes using ng-repeat Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Using ng-repeat I'm displaying Item related textboxes and on click of SaveAll button  I want to read all  text box values based on ITEM ID and Save it to DB.

```
<tr>
  <td>
     <table ng-repeat="item in itemDtls">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="lblItemName">Item ID: </label> {{item.ITEM_ID}} 
             </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td>
                <label for="lblPriority">Item Priority </label>
                <input type="text" id="inpPriority" ng-model="ValuesPriority" value="{{item.PRIORITY}}" />
              </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <label for="lblComment">Comment</label>
                <input type="text" id="inpComment" ng-model="ValuesComment" value="{{item.COMMENT}}" />
             </td>
          </tr>
      <tr>
  </table>
</td>
```

```
    <tr>
      <td>
         <button type="submit" ng-click="SaveAll()">SaveAll</button>
      </td>
   </tr>
```

Comment: what you've tried to store into db in the backend?

Comment: want to save all item details after modification of each item.

Comment: it requires backend code. i think it is not possible in javascript

Answer (score 1):

Do not use "value" tag instead use "ng-model" only.
Eg:

```
            <td>
           <label for="lblComment">Comment</label>
            <input type="text" id="inpComment" ng-model="item.COMMENT" />
         </td>
```

- So whatever comments you change, it will update in that variable.
- Later you can send "itemDtls" in backend to store in DB.
- You must need a backend to store in DB.